# Get objects from cosmos that are of the given class Type (ISO: Best Practice)

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

nuget library: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos v3.14.0

So its been a hot minute since ive worked around with Azure Cosmos. They seemed to have updated their SDK.
So what i am trying to figure out is if there is any way for me to get a list of records that match a class type.

My current idea is just to Interface all class objects that are stored in cosmos as a CosmosEntity that has a string of Type.
Then in this GetAll method I just check the item to see if it matches the given type.

Not really should how i would apply a filter in this without using a parameter and providing it the Type. Even considered using reflection but then if i am doing that every time its called im worried how that would impact performance.

Just trying to keep in best practice.

So! Question is!

What would be the best practice to get objects from cosmos that match the type of T?

```
    public async Task<List<T>> GetAllEntities<T>() where T : CosmosEntity, new()
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> result = new List<T>();
            using (FeedIterator<T> feedIterator = _cosmosDatabase.GetItemQueryIterator<T>())
            {
                while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (var item in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                    {                            
                        result.Add(item);
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var x = 1;
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have also the data model structure? Especially the PartitionKey is very important. F.e. you can use the PK as name of T so that your query is just reading all items from a partition. [But this really depends on your requirements.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview)

Comment: Since Cosmos just stores text and the type is a .NET construct, you would need some mechanism to identify the type of a record. I use a `type` property just as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow an approach like this:

```
public async Task<DocDbQueryResult> QueryCollectionWithPagingInternalAsync<T>(FeedOptions feedOptions, string queryString, IDictionary<string, object> queryParams, string collectionName)
        {
            string continuationToken = feedOptions.RequestContinuation;
            List<JObject> documents = new List<JObject>();
            IDictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            int executionCount = 0;
            double requestCharge = default(double);
            double totalRequestCharge = default(double);

            do
            {
                feedOptions.RequestContinuation = continuationToken;
                var query = this.documentDbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(this.databaseName, collectionName),
                    new SqlQuerySpec
                    {
                        QueryText = queryString,
                        Parameters = ToSqlQueryParamtereCollection(queryParams),
                    },
                    feedOptions)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

                var response = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<JObject>().ConfigureAwait(false);
                documents.AddRange(response.AsEnumerable());
                executionCount++;
                requestCharge = executionCount == 1 ? response.RequestCharge : requestCharge;
                totalRequestCharge += response.RequestCharge;
                continuationToken = response.ResponseContinuation;
            }
            while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(continuationToken) && documents.Count < feedOptions.MaxItemCount);

            var pagedDocuments = documents.Take(feedOptions.MaxItemCount.Value);
            var result = new DocDbQueryResult
            {
                ResultSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(new JArray(pagedDocuments).ToString()),
                TotalResults = Convert.ToInt32(pagedDocuments.Count()),
                ContinuationToken = continuationToken
            };

            // if query params are not null, use existing query params also to be passed as properties.
            if (queryParams != null)
            {
                properties = queryParams;
            }

            properties.Add("TotalRequestCharge", totalRequestCharge);
            properties.Add("ExecutionCount", executionCount);

            return result;
        }
```